# changes not getting reflected in github-pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I created a react app and deployed it in github-pages. Now I made some changes in the app and have pushed the changes to the master branch but I am not able to update changes in gh-pages branch, thus unable to see the updates in the gh-page deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

If those changes directly influence what is displayed by GitHub pages, it should be pushed to the `gh-pages` branches, not `master`.

You can follow, for testing, [`gitname/react-gh-pages`](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) to try and create a react app on `gh-pages`.